# What do "Lookup Down" & "Lookup Up" actions do in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

When I was going to assign <kbd>ctrl+down/up</kbd> to <kbd>f3</kbd> & <kbd>shift+f3</kbd>
I came across these two commands which had the same keyboard shortcut:

"Lookup Down" and "Lookup up"
Location: file > setting > keymap > other

Couldn't find anything about them. After removing ctrl+up/down from the scroll up/down action I tried them in editor space but they don't lookup/down for the previous searched word. any ideas?

More generally, is there any complete documentation/help for android studio? 
These links doesn't seem to have such a complete documentation
http://tools.android.com/
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html
Also couldn't find anything on IntelliJ IDEA help.

Comment: Anything not already said on  http://tools.android.com/ in mentioned in the Intellij documentation because that is the actual base IDE

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is based on JetBrains' Intellij IDEA, so most of the information you're looking for would be the same regarding the IDE.

I'm not sure about the specific shortcut you mentioned, but you can find a complete default-assigned shortcuts reference link inside Android Studio's help menu named "Default Keymap Reference".